# Edit the Jet Framework

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-jet

Is it actually possible to edit the javascript from [Jet Framework](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/index.html) from Oracle.
I want to edit the Javascript from the Jet Framework that it doesn't do a line break after a line. And they should overlap themselv. That means it looks like this:

---

**wwwwww**

---

The character **w** are 2 labels overlaping. And this is important they have to overlap themselv.

[image]

So it should look that all labels are on the same field. I have done this in the Javascript from the Debug Version.

**PS:** The Jetframework has two versions, when you download the Framework, the minified version and the dubug version.

My Javascript works fine but in the Jet Framework it should be minified. **So here my Question:** What minifyer uses the Jet Framework to minifye the Javascript.

Sources:

[Picture](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=basic)

**PS** I am sorry for my bad english. English is not my native Language. When you have questions please Ask in the Comments.

Thanks in Advance

Ivo

Comment: I think it's [Grunt](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet220/jet/developer/GUID-661048AC-2510-4BFC-A1EA-944BEDF1C620.htm#JETDG-GUID-7158F1A6-14AE-4CAB-95F9-BC24B2C53472)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the goal?

Comment: What I want to achieve is that the grunt "Labels" can overlapp themself in one line.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any need to hack into the JavaScript for this.  Just use CSS as it should be used.  Look at the browser dev tools to see which classes are handling the labels and adjust the CSS to get the overlap settings that you want.

Comment: just override the css classes that are used.